# Rust return array with same or different size

Tags: rust

Is it possible to return array with same or different size

```
fn get_data_if_opened<const N: usize>(production_move: [i32; N]) ->  {  
  if condition { return production_move; }
  production_move.push(1);
  return production_move;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rust wants "monomorphic" return types, so if you want multiple return types you need an enum to dynamically dispatch the information.

You'll also need a macro like [`concat_array`](https://docs.rs/concat-arrays/latest/concat_arrays/macro.concat_arrays.html), as currently I don't think the stdlib supports "extending" arrays, except possibly by round-tripping through a vector.